# Dynamically update page based on an instance variable from Ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, partial

Update:  My question was answered, but I wrote a blog post detailing exactly how I went about doing this:  http://lathamcity.com/posts/ajaxInRails.html

I have a page that shows a list of things based on a Ruby object.  My goal is to make an Ajax call to get a new Ruby object and then update the list based on that.

I thought that the way to do this was with partials.  I make the entire list a partial file with the Rails instance variable in the code.  Then I want the Ajax call to set the corresponding instance variable to the new list and re-render the partial.

That's the end goal, but right now I'm trying to do a really basic version of that where I just set an instance variable to a string and then show the string.

So in my div, I have:

```
<% form_tag :action => :go , :method => :get, :remote => true  do %>
    <%= submit_tag "Go" %>
<% end %>

<div id="test"><%= render(:partial => 'test') %></div>
```

There's a _test.erb file in the `views/interface` (the name of my controller) folder, with only the following line as its contents:

```
<%= @test %>
```

And then in my controller,

```
def go
    @test = "Hello You"
    render :update do |page|
        page.replace_html "test", :partial => "test"
    end
end
```

When I run this, I get:  `Missing template interface/update, application/update`

I don't know much about `render :update`, I found it in an example on Google.

What am I doing wrong that is causing this problem and how can I fix it?  Am I going about this the right way or is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think both `render :update` and `replace_html` were deprecated/removed in rails 3.1. The standard way of doing partial updates is to use a js.erb template.

In your controller, tell your action to respond to js request:

```
@test = "Hello you"
respond_to do |format|
    format.js
end
```

Create the js response template app/views/interface/go.js.erb:

```
$('#test').html("<%= escape_javascript(render('test', test: @test})) %>")
```

and change the partial code to `<%= test %>` because this is no longer an instance variable; rather, test is being passed to the partial as an argument from the js.erb template with `test: @test`